# iview problem about i-select's change event

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, iview

http://jsfiddle.net/gx1jyq9k/6/

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="tab">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" @click="tab=0">TAB1</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" @click="tab=1">TAB2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-panels">
    <template v-if="tab==0">
     <i-select v-model="sharp">
       <i-option :value="0">Circle</i-option>
       <i-option :value="1">Square</i-option>
     </i-select>
    </template>
    <template v-if="tab==1">
     <i-select v-model="color" @on-change="changeColor">
       <i-option value="red">Red</i-option>
       <i-option value="blue">Blue</i-option>
     </i-select>
    </template>
  </div>
</div>

var app = new Vue({
    el:"#app",
    data:{
    tab:0,
    sharp:0,
    color:''
       },
    methods:{
      changeColor:function(){
        alert('Color is changed!');
         }
       }
    })
```

When I click the tab 'TAB2', why trigger the event 'changeColor',I think the problem caused by component reuse,but how can I fix it,who can help me how to do,thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your guess, the problem is component re-use.

You can add `key` to `i-select` to prevent this problem

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="tab">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" @click="tab=0">TAB1</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" @click="tab=1">TAB2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-panels">
   <template v-if="tab==0">
       <i-select v-model="sharp" key="tab1">
         <i-option :value="0">Circle</i-option>
         <i-option :value="1">Square</i-option>
       </i-select>
   </template>
   <template v-if="tab==1">
       <i-select v-model="color" @on-change="changeColor" key="tab2">
           <i-option value="red">Red</i-option>
           <i-option value="blue">Blue</i-option>
       </i-select>
   </template>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/ittus/697towmq/1/)

Comment: ha,I came up with the key solution,but I add key to ’i-option‘，so I did't fix it.the exact way is adding key to i-select,thank you very much,big god!!

Answer (score 0):

```
 <i-option :value="red">Red</i-option>
 <i-option :value="blue">Blue</i-option>

var app = new Vue({
    el:"#app",
    data:{
    tab:0,
    sharp:0,
    color:'red'
       },
    methods:{
      changeColor:function(){
        alert('Color is changed!');
         }
       }
    })
```

Try to add default value for color!

And please add ":" before value="red" and value="blue"